# 'end' undefined for this.response in Iron Router for Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have created an HTTP POST endpoint for my Meteor server using Iron Router. I would like to send a response back to the requestor with a JSON of the status and some other metadata.

Here is the code for the endpoint:

```
Router.route('/new_video', {where: 'server'})
.post(function(){

    var body = this.request.body;
    this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var filename = body.filename;


    console.log('New video uploaded for: ' + filename);

    Meteor.call('newUpload', filename, function(error, results){
        if (error){
            throw new Meteor.Error("new-video-upload-failed", "New video could not be uploaded.");
            var message = {
                url: '/new_video',
                status: 'success'
            };
        }
        else{
            var videoId = results;
            console.log('Returned video id: ' + videoId);
            var message = {
                url: '/new_video',
                status: 'failure'
            };
        }

        this.response.end(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
});
```

The Meteor console is printing:

```
=> Meteor server restarted
I20151002-15:51:26.311(-4)? New recording for: 1422776235,43.46756387,-80.54130886.mp4
I20151002-15:51:26.515(-4)? Returned video id: QiHXxZSb2sn9aNRPs
I20151002-15:51:26.569(-4)? Exception in delivering result of invoking 'newRecording': TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' of undefined
I20151002-15:51:26.569(-4)?     at shared/routes.js:79:17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common pitfall of JS where the value of `this` is modified due to the introduction of another function callback in the `Meteor.call`.

If you're using Meteor 1.2 which comes with ES2015 arrow functions you can solve the issue using this function declaration syntax instead :

```
Meteor.call('newUpload', filename, (error, results) => {
  // here 'this' will keep referencing the POST route context
  // so you can safely use this.response
});
```

If you're not using Meteor 1.2, use this syntax instead :

```
Meteor.call('newUpload', filename, function(error, results) {
  // inner function is bound to parent function 'this'
}.bind(this));
```